# call database build function like COL_NAME, COLUMNPROPERTY etc.. form other database scope

Tags: sql-server

there is a  way to call [Metadata Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/metadata-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 
from another database
for this example

```
Use TempDB
SELECT AdventureWorks2014.Sys.COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('AdventureWorks2014.Person.Address'),2)
```

i got

```
Cannot find either column "AdventureWorks2014" or the user-defined function or aggregate "AdventureWorks2014.Sys.COL_NAME", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Comment: `COL_NAME` is an in-built function, it runs under the context of the database you are connected to. It doesn't exist in the database like the `sys` objects. it's not `sys.COL_NAME()` it's just `COL_NAME`.

Comment: COLUMN_NAME is an example of my issue ,its a part of statement works on some db, and the statement needs to move to another DB

Comment: Then show us the *real* problem you have.

Comment: You can put the statements inside a stored procedure and call it externally -- that will resolve in the called database, not the calling one -- but as the output of stored procedures is hard to use this is rarely very helpful. Stick with explicitly-scoped system views (`AdventureWorks2014.sys.columns`, `AdventureWorks2014.sys.objects`) or better yet client code that connects to the right database(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query can help to solve your issue particularly for column names so that you can get all column names from the other databases;

```
use AnyDatabase
select * from AdventureWorks2017.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'Person' and 
COLUMN_NAME = 'PersonType'

+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
|   TABLE_CATALOG    | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | COLUMN_DEFAULT | IS_NULLABLE | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX | NUMERIC_SCALE | DATETIME_PRECISION | CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG | CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | COLLATION_CATALOG | COLLATION_SCHEMA |        COLLATION_NAME        | DOMAIN_CATALOG | DOMAIN_SCHEMA | DOMAIN_NAME |
+--------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
| AdventureWorks2017 | Person       | Person     | PersonType  |                2 | NULL           | NO          | nchar     |                        2 |                      4 | NULL              | NULL                    | NULL          | NULL               | NULL                  | NULL                 | UNICODE            | NULL              | NULL             | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS | NULL           | NULL          | NULL
```